# Make an average from two values on two rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have to make an array in this form :

```php
$averages
(
    'time' => array
    (
        'server1' => average1,
        'server2' => average2,
        'servers' => average
    )
)
```

I get the values from a mysql table designed this way :
idServer   | value1 | value2

'servers' average should get:

value1(server1)+value1(server2) /  value1(server1)+value1(server2)+value2(server1)+value2(server2)

What is the most elegant way to calculate the final average without queering everytime or creating an array localy before processing it ? (which are the only two solutions I can think about)

Comment: What do you mean, "querying every time"? If you are getting all these values from your MySQL server you can perform your aggregation within the query itself. If you have to continuously query for data, you are going to have to run either the SQL or PHP each time anyway.

Comment: Sorry for my weak English, what I want to say is that I already fetch those data to calculate the two fist averages. So the question is : Is there a way to get the final one without doing a new query ?

Comment: You need to clarify a little better what it is you are attempting to accomplish, but if you have the necessary server resources (check the RAM allocated to the PHP pool using phpinfo() (memory_limit) and the size of the data set, you should be able to pull the entire contents of the table into said array and just for-loop through them to calculate the individual averages. That would calculate in seconds rather than minutes or hours since you are utilizing local resources (fast) rather than making repeat calls to a db server (slow).

Comment: So to clarify, `value1(server1)` is value one from a specific server  and `value1(server2)` is another value from a different server?

Comment: Yes and the final one is the average on both servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I got is to get the number of servers first. Then to make the sql query's columns number depending on that. I think it is not possible to adjust the number of columns requested dynamically.